# Xamarin iOS app crashing on startup only in release mode. xamarin_initialize EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

Crash log from testflight. can't reproduce in debug mode. Haven't changed anything near startup recently that I can think of. did update visual studio recently, which is always risky. Any ideas on where to look? I'm currently at a loss.

```
Incident Identifier: A16565BD-14CB-422F-8201-1F83E62D0636
Beta Identifier: 9AC85708-52C8-4855-9C08-F86429C52CA2
Hardware Model: iPhone11,6
Process: app [47469]
Path: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DEBBDCD7-7D27-4B7D-AB2E-22D5C399BA37/app/app
Identifier:
Version: 2 (2.6.3)
AppStoreTools: 11C29
AppVariant: 1:iPhone11,6:13
Beta: YES
Code Type: ARM-64 (Native)
Role: Foreground
Parent Process: launchd [1]
Coalition:

Date/Time: 2019-12-13 12:32:17.7284 -0600
Launch Time: 2019-12-13 12:32:17.1647 -0600
OS Version: iPhone OS 13.2.3 (17B111)
Release Type: User
Baseband Version: 2.02.12
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region. Bytes before following region: 4295278592
REGION TYPE START - END [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD REGION DETAIL
UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->
__TEXT 000000010004c000-0000000100164000 [ 1120K] r-x/r-x SM=COW ...toGrindersiOS

Triggered by Thread: 0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001a094eefc __pthread_kill + 8
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001a086ed10 pthread_kill + 196 (pthread.c:1456)
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00000001a07feaf4 __abort + 116 (abort.c:147)
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00000001a07fea80 abort + 116 (abort.c:118)
4 appname 0x0000000101a38ca0 xamarin_initialize.cold.1 + 0
5 appname 0x0000000101a2ef54 xamarin_printf + 27144020 (runtime.m:2541)
6 appname 0x00000001018f8ad8 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 132
7 appname 0x000000010188d68c mono_handle_exception_internal + 5580
8 appname 0x000000010188c0b4 mono_handle_exception + 56
9 appname 0x0000000101881c2c mono_arm_throw_exception + 376
10 appname 0x000000010043433c throw_exception + 172
11 appname 0x00000001019686a8 mono_raise_exception + 64
12 appname 0x0000000101a2ed6c xamarin_process_managed_exception + 27143532 (runtime.m:2497)
13 appname 0x0000000101a2f458 xamarin_initialize + 27145304 (runtime.m:979)
14 appname 0x0000000101a360e4 xamarin_main + 27173092 (monotouch-main.m:432)
15 appname 0x0000000100165878 main + 1153144 (main.m:142)
16 libdyld.dylib 0x00000001a0958e18 start + 4
```

Comment: Are you using the same device with same iOS version to test in debug mode? Is there any difference in your project between debug and release mode? The error information you shared does not help much.

Comment: yes it's the same device and version of iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future me or anyone that runs into something similar, I solved this with some framework updates/downgrades. I haven't narrowed it down to the exact issue because i did several at once based on what the project was asking for and past experience.

The main change I made that I think is the most likely culprit was a downgrade of Xamarin.Build.Download to 0.4.11. Sorry I can't be more helpful.